# Android Activity restarts after Unlocking device

Tags: android, android-activity

I am creating a simple Android project. But my every activity gets Restart when user unlock the screen(after locking). Is it normal behavior of android app? OR i have to handle it in Manifest? or some where else? Please Help...

Comment: What do you mean by restarts? What impacts does it have on you application which you want to avoid?

Comment: U mean about your activity behaviour or the operation that you are performing is restarts ?

Comment: Actually in activity onCreate() downloads on image and shows in ImageView. But if image is download and device gets locked, and after unlocking device manually, OnCreate of activity gets called again. that's what i want to avoid.

Comment: Ya actually onCreate() of activity gets called.

Comment: Need to add  android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden" in manifest for every Activity. And is resolves the problem

        <activity
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
            android:name="YOUR ACTIVITY NAME">
        </activity>

Answer (score 15):

If your target build version is Honeycomb 3.2 (API Level 13) or higher you must put the screenSize flag too, as in:

```
<activity
    android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboardHidden"
    android:name="YOUR ACTIVITY NAME">
</activity>
```

because even with the "orientation" flag you app will be killed and recreated again with every orientation change when your app is the active one, either being visible on screen or hidden by the lock screen. This is because the usable screen size, mainly in tablets, actually changes due to the change in placement of the system action bar.

This drove me crazy for hours! :/

Comment: Documentations also says that "screenSize" is needed only if your targetSdkVersion is 13 or higher. Otherwise, your activity will handle the configuration change itself (this configuration change does not restart your activity, even when running on an Android 3.2 or higher device).

Comment: Indeed you are completely right, that's why I stated it at the top of the answer. Only if you build target (not minSdkVersion but targetSdkVersion) is 13 or higher this flag must be supplied. If the app is started in any older android version, the flag will be ignored altogether.

Comment: worked as expected. In my case for SOME devices I had app suddenly closes after unlock screen. And fixed it by adding this screenSize to all activities' configchanges. Thank You soo much!

Answer (score 4):

Need to add  `android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"` in manifest for every Activity. And is resolves the problem

```
    <activity
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
        android:name="YOUR ACTIVITY NAME">
    </activity>
```