# Fix for restart on configChanges such as unlock device

Tags: android

I am implementing a fix similar to the one outlined here -

[Android Activity restarts after Unlocking device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8426910/android-activity-restarts-after-unlocking-device)

However, I am not sure about the difference between -

difference between

```
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboard"
```

and

```
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboard|keyboardHidden"
```

Does anyone know the exact difference between the above two attributes in the Activity section in the AndroidManifest?

Answer (score 0):

According to http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#config:

- "keyboard"   The keyboard type has changed — for example, the user has plugged in an external keyboard.
- "keyboardHidden" The keyboard accessibility has changed — for example, the user has revealed the hardware keyboard.

You typically want to use orientation|keyboardHidden in your AndroidManifest.xml - that will catch most instances of activity restarts (screen rotation & physical keyboard being displayed). Some people recommend throwing in keyboard for good measure as well to catch additional instances of the activity being restarted. I personally haven't seen an instance of the 'keyboard' event being raised.